# Error when tuning a support vector regression model in R

Tags: regression, svm

I am exploring support vector machine regression with this tutorial http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/support-vector-regression-r/. I encounter  `Error in do.call(method, c(list(train.x, data = data, subset = train.ind[[sample]]), : 'what' must be a function or character string` when tuning the model using grid search but I am not sure what that means. Here are the codes I used: 
`svm_m <- svm(FuelRate~ Heading+Distance+Elevatio+YieldDry+HarvestM, data = fr_tr)`
`tuneResult <- tune(svm_m, FuelRate ~ Heading+Distance+Elevatio+YieldDry+HarvestM, data = fr_tr, ranges = list(epsilon = seq(0,1,0.1), cost=2^(2:9)))`. Can anyone teach me about the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I used a wrong argument here `tuneResult <- tune(svm_m, FuelRate ~ Heading+Distance+Elevatio+YieldDry+HarvestM, data = fr_tr, ranges = list(epsilon = seq(0,1,0.1), cost=2^(2:9)))`. The first argument should be `method = svm`.